# How to get distance to from many points to destination?

Tags: python, google-maps

I have code:

```
    orig_lat = 48.864716  # Paris lat
    orig_lon = 2.349014  # Paris lon
    dest_lat = 52.518623
    dest_lon = 13.376198

    google_url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/'
    fn_url = 'distancematrix/'
    opt_url = '&language=en-EN&sensor=false'

    url = "%s%sjson?origins=%s,%s&destinations=%s,%s&mode=driving%s" % (
        google_url, fn_url, str(orig_lat), str(orig_lon),
        str(dest_lat), str(dest_lon), opt_url
    )

    ret = requests.get(url)
```

and google response:

```
{
    "destination_addresses" : [ "Paul-Löbe-Allee, 10557 Berlin, Germany" ],
    "origin_addresses" : [ "18bis Rue Tiquetonne, 75002 Paris, France" ],
    "rows" : [
         {
            "elements" : [
                {
                    "distance" : {
                        "text" : "1,045 km",
                        "value" : 1045157
                    },
                    "duration" : {
                        "text" : "9 hours 58 mins",
                        "value" : 35905
                    },
                    "status" : "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

But I have one destination point and many origin points:

```
dest_lat = 52.518623
dest_lon = 13.376198

origins = [
    (48.864716, 2.349014),  # Paris
    (40.415363, -3.707398),  # Madrid
    (52.237049, 21.017532)  # Warsaw
]
```

I want to get all durations and distance in one request. Is this possible?

Comment: In one request? I'm not sure if google has that kind of functionality. Maybe try to iterate over the origins and do a request for each one and append the results to your data structure

Comment: yeah, as above. youll have to use a for loop to iterate over origins!

Comment: That is what the distance matrix does, what issue are you having?

Comment: Heh, sadly. I have many points and many requests for their distances. Forloop generates huge number of requests.

Answer (score 1):

As geocodezip pointed out, this is a standard feature of the distance matrix.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=48.864716,2.349014|40.415363,-3.707398|52.237049,21.017532&destinations=52.518623,13.376198&key=YOUR_API_KEY